# PHP Contact Form GDPR Validation

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have a contact form that I manage to make work.

The form has some fields, the reCaptcha and a consent check box.

The PHP code is like this:

```
    if($_POST)
    {

    $to_Email       = "contact@blabla.com"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Form contact'; //Subject line for emails


    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
            array(
                'type'=>'error',
                'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
            ));

        die($output);
    }

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]) || !isset($_POST["userprivacy"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'It is necessary to fill in all the fields and validate the terms and conditions box.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Subject =  $_POST["userSubject"];
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $customer_privacy     = filter_var($_POST["userprivacy"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<3) // If length is less than 3 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }


    $message_Body = "<strong>Name: </strong>". $user_Name ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Email: </strong>". $user_Email ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Empresa: </strong>". $user_Subject ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Message: </strong>". $user_Message ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Message: </strong>". $customer_privacy ."<br>";



    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($user_Email) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($user_Email) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";



    //proceed with PHP email.
    /*$headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    */


    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $message_Body, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hola '.$user_Name .' Gracias por contactanos, en breve nos pondremos en contacto contigo.'));
        die($output);
    }
}
```

And the HTML like this:

```
<form class="getin_form wow fadeInUp">
            <div class="col-sm-12" id="result"></div>
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                 <div class="form-group bottom45">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="user_name"  required>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                 <div class="form-group bottom45">
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Correo Eletronico" required>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                 <div class="form-group bottom45">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Empresa">
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                 <div class="form-group bottom45">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="user_message" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
                 </div>

                 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>   
                    <form action="?" method="POST">
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"></div>   
              </div>

              <div>
                 <div class="col-md-1 checker" id="uniform-customer_privacy">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="0" required  name="customer_privacy" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                 <div><span>He&nbsp;le&iacute;do&nbsp;y&nbsp;acepto&nbsp;los&nbsp;<span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong><a href="http://blablabla.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">T&eacute;rminos&nbsp;y&nbsp;condiciones</a></strong></span>&nbsp;de&nbsp;blablabla.</span></div>
              </div>
              
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <button type="button"  class="button defaulthole" id="submit_btn">Enviar</button>
              </div>
           </div>
        </form>
```

When I fill out the form and press send, I still get the error that it is not completed.

I don't know if I'm putting any variables wrong - I don't really understand why it's not working.

[image: Capture]

Comment: The names of the input fields and what you're trying to fetch in PHP are different. Example: `name="user_email"` and `$_POST['userEmail']` (this goes for all inputs)

Comment: I recommend that you [read through the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) about handling forms.

Comment: Added img as img (not as link), removed unnecessary text.